# MouseIn and MouseOut animation only in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to reveal a part of my CV and the mouse is over "CV" and then details appears. I managed the first part but when the mouse go away the div, this is too gross.

Take a look here : https://codepen.io/Lynkas/pen/wRdger

Thanks ♥

```
<div class="contenu">
        <div class="cv"><span>CV →</span>
            <div class="cvv">
                <h1>EXPÉRIENCES</h1>
                <table class='mttb'>
                    <tr class='mttr'>
                        <td class='mttd'><b>AOÛT 2016</b></td>
                        <td class='mttd'><b>JOB D'ÉTÉ , BUREAU INFORMATION JEUNESSE<br>LES MUREAUX</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='mttr'>
                        <td class='mttd'><b>JANVIER - JUIN 2016</b></td>
                        <td class='mttd'><b>BÉNÉVOLAT (78)</b><br><br>• A.P.I. (Atelier Pédagogique Individualisé)<br>animation d’un atelier découverte de l’informatique<br><br>• Mission locale + i.M.E. alfred binet<br>+ A.C.R. (Agir Combattre Réunir)<br>création de flyers, affiches et faire-parts<br>montage d’une vidéo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='mttr'>
                        <td class='mttd'><b>MARS - AVRIL 2016</b></td>
                        <td class='mttd'><b>DIAM (ENTREPRISE PLURISDISCIPLINAIRE)<br>LES MUREAUX</b><br><br>• web : création d’un prototype d’une matériauthèque web<br><br>• communication audiovisuelle :<br>montage vidéo : découpe, disposition<br>retouche colorimétrique<br><br>• communication visuelle :<br>création d’une carte géographique avec géolocalisation<br>des objectifs, présentations PowerPoint</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`transition`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) instead `animation`

[Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/fhmjgsbp/)

```css
.contenu {
    margin-left: 150px;
    padding: 100px;
}

.cv {
    background: #27ae60;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s 0.2s,width 1s;}

.cv:hover {
   height: 630px;
   width:auto;
}

.cv span {
    color: white;
}

.cvv {
    width: 50%;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.mttb{
}
.mttb th{
}
.mttb td {
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenu">
 <div class="cv"><span>CV →</span>
 <div class="cvv">
 <h1>EXPÉRIENCES</h1>
 <table class='mttb'>
 <tr class='mttr'>
 <td class='mttd'><b>AOÛT 2016</b></td>
 <td class='mttd'><b>JOB D'ÉTÉ , BUREAU INFORMATION JEUNESSE<br>LES MUREAUX</b></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class='mttr'>
 <td class='mttd'><b>JANVIER - JUIN 2016</b></td>
 <td class='mttd'><b>BÉNÉVOLAT (78)</b><br><br>• A.P.I. (Atelier Pédagogique Individualisé)<br>animation d’un atelier découverte de l’informatique<br><br>• Mission locale + i.M.E. alfred binet<br>+ A.C.R. (Agir Combattre Réunir)<br>création de flyers, affiches et faire-parts<br>montage d’une vidéo</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class='mttr'>
 <td class='mttd'><b>MARS - AVRIL 2016</b></td>
 <td class='mttd'><b>DIAM (ENTREPRISE PLURISDISCIPLINAIRE)<br>LES MUREAUX</b><br><br>• web : création d’un prototype d’une matériauthèque web<br><br>• communication audiovisuelle :<br>montage vidéo : découpe, disposition<br>retouche colorimétrique<br><br>• communication visuelle :<br>création d’une carte géographique avec géolocalisation<br>des objectifs, présentations PowerPoint</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so coo ! but it's still gross :( 
When the mouse is over I want width first and then height, and when the mouse go away I want the reverse animation like my demo link but when the mouse go away it's I want an animation but reverse. I search on web since yesterday :(

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.
I see what you're trying to do, 
Possible solutions would be:

### **1. The solution with the "transition" attribute:**

---

```
transition: width, height 0.5s ease;/*1.here you specify the attributes you want the transition on*//*2.the length of the transition animation*//*3.the type of transition(e.g. liner, ease, boolean*/
```

### **2. The solution with "animation"**

---

The reason why the animation cvOut is not executed in your code is, because you didn't specify when this should happen. You need to state that when the element is not hovered upon, the animation cvOut should start.
This would look something like here:

```css
.cv:not(:hover) {
  animation: cvout 1s;
}
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you wanted something else!

Comment: Same problem with transition attribute, width animation doesn't appears, I think we can make the width animation and then after 1 or 2s the height animation ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you both ! I find something interesting, the problem was width: auto

```
.cv:hover {
height: 630px;
width: auto;}
```

so I remplace it by width: 100%

```
.cv:hover {
height: 630px;
width: 100%;}
```

and it's works ! But when the mouse leave I want a reverse animation. When the mouse is on : width and height ; and when the mouse leave height and then width. Is it possible ?

```
.cv {
background: #27ae60;
padding: 10px;
height: 20px;
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: width 1s ease, height 3s 1s ease;}

.cv:hover {
height: 630px;
width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

```
.cv {
background: #27ae60;
padding: 10px;
height: 20px;
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: height .5s ease, width 1s .5s ease;}

.cv:hover {
height: 630px;
width: 100%;
transition: width .5s ease, height 1s .5s ease;}
```